# Newbie of netbeans 7 and glassfish3

Tags: netbeans, glassfish-3

I just installed Netbeans 7.0.1 with glassfish 3 on my Windows XP box. I started to learn some JSF and tried to launch it. But glassfish failed to start:

```
SEVERE: Shutting down v3 due to startup exception : No free port within range: 8080=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectorHandler@1815aa4
```

and

```
Deployment error:
GlassFish Server 3.1 Start Failed
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:223)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 32 seconds)
```

It looks like port 8080 is being used (I confirmed there is another application running on 8080 I cann not change). How can I reconfigure Netbeans and glassfish to run on some other port?

Thanks

Hardy

Comment: OK, after some search I found the solution http://www.sandeepsachan.com/netbeans-glassfish-change-default-port.html and it works for me.

Comment: Add that as an answer and select it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Find your Glassfish install directory (e.g. `C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1`)
2. Find the domain.xml file located under the install directory: `\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml`
3. Open in a text editor
4. Search for 8080. You should find this under the XML node named: `network-listener`.
5. Change 8080 to a more appropriate port (I had to try more than once since my next try of 8086 was also used by something else).